# Не могу получить доступ к элементу, на который указывает указатель структуры

Tags: c++

```
struct spisarg
{
    sock sockets;
    int maximum_packet_sizeS;
    sockaddr_in from,address[];
    int lineS;
    int schetlineS;
    WAVHEADER wavhead;
} spisarguments;

struct spisarg *Pspisarguments;
Pspisarguments = &spisarguments;
```

Потом передаю функцию и список аргументов в поток:

```
_beginthread( priempackets, 0, (void *) Pspisarguments);
```

вот сама функция:

```
void priempackets(void * Pspisarguments)
{
    int *paketdata = new int [2000000000];
    int schetchik =0;
    Pspisarguments->lineS--;
```

В строчке `Pspisarguments->lineS--;` ошибка:

> ```
> [BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(280): E2288 Pointer to structure required on left side of -> or ->*
> ```

Если пишу так: `(*Pspisarguments)->lineS--;` то:

> ```
> [BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(280): E2109 Not an allowed type
> ```

Comment: Вы так бодро запрашиваете почти 2 гигабайта памяти... Они вам точно нужны?

Comment: ну да вдруг звуковой файл будет столько места занимать))

Answer (score 3):

```
void priempackets(void * Pspisarguments)
{
    Pspisarguments->lineS--;
```

Ну все верно - ведь у вас `Pspisarguments` имеет тип `void*`. Приведите его к типу, который передавали - `struct spisarg *`. Хотя бы

```
((struct spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->lineS--;
```

Только у вас судя по коду - никак не C++, а чистый C, даже слово `struct` d

```
struct spisarg *Pspisarguments;
```

об этом говорит...

Comment: ну да, прост си и у с++ одинаковый синтаксис,если речь не о компонентах

Comment: сделал так ((struct spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->lineS--; теперь 
[BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(280): E2315 'lineS' is not a member of 'spisarg', because the type is not yet defined

Comment: Ну а этот тип - структура - у вас определен **до** использования? Послушайте, ну это уже совершенно детская ошибка, компилятор так и пишет... Если вы намерены заниматься программированием, то должны знать английский, чтобы прочесть *"E2315 'lineS' не является членом 'spisarg', потому что этот тип еще не определен"*. Куда уж понятнее! Определите тип до его использования - что тут непонятно?!

Comment: так он определён struct spisarg
 {
     sock sockets;
  int maximum_packet_sizeS;
     sockaddr_in from,address[];
  int lineS;

Comment: я же не могу опять в своей функции объявлять структуру, где опять надо декларировать все элементы. Ведь тогда я потеряю их значения, которые мне передаются из главной функции.

Comment: @Daunich, поместите объявление `struct spisarg` в .h файл и включайте его во все .cpp файлы, где используется эта структура